# How to play a movie from Ubuntu desktop on Kodi?

Tags: kodi, dlna

I can play (share) a movie from my Android phone to Kodi on a Raspberry PI with, for example, the Android app: Yatse.

I think that is using a DLNA server on the Kodi and using Android as DLNA client (?).

My question is: Can I do that from Ubuntu desktop?

Play a file (music, video) from Ubuntu and see it on Kodi?

Comment: Yes, the situation you described seems to be DLNA (or UPnP). Yatse is mostly a non-official remote control app for a (desktop) Kodi with additional streaming functions by UPnP, AirPlay or Chromecast. Regarding your actual question, it isn't clear what do you intend. Kodi runs natively in Ubuntu, plays local or network files and can work as a "UPnP server" and share all its library to the network. What exactly do you mean by "play a file from Ubuntu and see it on Kodi"?

Comment: I'll create a fix :) Thanks for your help @MichaelBay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu 19.10**’s new ‘**Media Sharing**’ toggle in `Settings > Sharing` means you can share media photos, videos and music over your local network. It all works using the **ubiquitous DLNA/UPnP protocols** and your local network — no third-party cloud server or media centre set-up required. (Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server)).

1. To **activate** media sharing in Ubuntu 19.10 just pop open the main Settings app and select the ‘Sharing’ option in the sidebar:
   [image]
2. **Click on the ‘Media Sharing’ option** that’s greyed out in the main pane. A small modal dialogue will appear:
   [image]
3. Slide the switcher in the header bar of the modal dialogue to ‘On’, and then select a network from the list to share your media on.
   *Disclaimer: DLNA sharing isn’t a secure way to share media. Everyone on the same network can access (but not edit/delete) shared media.*
4. You’ll notice that 3 folders are shared by default: Pictures, Videos and Music. **If you don’t want to share one/any of these just remove them** from the list using the x ion to the right of the folder name.
5. **To add your own media sources** just scroll down the dialogue and hit the + button. Then use the folder picker to navigate to and select a different folder on your system. Repeat the process to add additional directories.

**For more details,** please read [the article on OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server).

It looks like it is based on [Rygel](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel) and this tool is now integrated in Ubuntu. Be careful [it sometimes autostarts by default/mistake after upgrading to 19.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rygel/+bug/1848692) but a fix is on its way (Nov 2019). (Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/rygel-autostart-media-sharing-bug-ubuntu).)

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark your answer as solution, it's more simple an easy. Best regards.

Comment: @Costales Thank you for the mark and vote! Hopefully it works well for you, the new feature may need some (development) time to fully shine.

Answer (score 5):

I want to play on Raspberry PI with Kodi my videos from Ubuntu desktop.
My workaround was:

- Install [miniDLNA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA) on Ubuntu desktop. This will be the DLNA server.
- On Raspberry PI (Kodi), add an UPnP source, it will find the Ubuntu source, then you can play videos from it :)

Best regards.